# Express.js Date Validation

Tags: javascript, schema

I want to validate the jointdate using currentdate.
if jointdate is greater than current date I want to throw an error code.
    Using Schema level validation
Schema:

```
var datevalidation=function(value){
        return value.joindate>value.now+1;
    }
    var EmployeeSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    joindate:{
        type:Date,
        validate:[datevalidation,'please enter correct date']
    }
})
```